# Check when script has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am trying to call a function that, on the load of the script above it, will run some JavaScript.

```
<script src="../Layout/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helperscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var itemid = '1';
        if(itemid)
        {
            idselect(itemid);
        }
    })
</script>
```

helperscript.js contains the function `idselect`.
When I load the page I get an error saying that `'idselect is undefined'`, even though it is in the above file. I suspect that this is due to helperscript not being fully loaded yet, but that is just a hunch.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if the answers still don't solve your problem please post relevant part of `helperscript.js` showing how that function is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts load in order and are blocking.

There must be a problem with the loading of the script, not the timing.

Most likely you have either a mistake in the URL (resulting in a 404) or a JavaScript error (which would show up on the error console)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your hunch is right, because this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helperscript.js"></script>
```

should block any other javascript from executing until helperscript.js is downloaded and executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.getScript() and register a success function. It will be safe to use idselect on or after the success function is executed.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path to the script to the **.js** file is correct.

Also cut the `language="javascript"` part.